# Set up Gmail IMAP on Thunderbird 3

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail, imap

I can't seem to get Thunderbird 3 and Gmail to work together. I've been a Thunderbird user for years, and I have a different Google mail account set up and working already which successfully migrated in from Thunderbird 2.

I'm not even sure at what end the problem is. I *think* I have the client set up right, and I *think* the strange cryptic error message I get is from Thunderbird:

> **Alert**
>   Web login required (Failure)

On the Gmail side I have logged in to my account and enabled IMAP. The settings I see in their how-to for Thunderbird 2 all seem to be set right in Thunderbird 3.

I'm at a complete loss as to what else I can check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed NOTHING - I just waited about an hour, during which time I did log in to the web interface, then, it just started working in Thunderbird. No changes were made on either end.

I guess when ever you get the above error the answer is to be patient.

It's possible I triggered all this by accidentally repeatedly entering the wrong password the first time I tries to access the account from TB. It's also possible that it takes some time for the change in settings to allow IMAP to take effect.

Comment: or, might be Gmail was having some problems

Answer (score 1):

Are these IMAP [settings](http://www.google.co.uk/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=4b2d591a19e418f7&hl=en) the answer?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a different google mail account
>   set up and working

Have you enabled IMAP in the Mail account you're trying to add to Thunderbird 3 ?

[image: Image courtesy How-To Geek]

*Image courtesy [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/internet/setting-up-gmail-imap-support-in-thunderbird-2x/)*

This [Google groups discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/Gmail-Help-POP-and-IMAP-en/browse_thread/thread/0cb44e7c32a56e1a) indicates few other Non-Thunderbird users are also facing the same problem. You might want to try

- Enable `Always use SSL`
- [Use the unlock CAPTCHA link](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=14257)

Comment: As I said in my question, yes, I have enabled IMAP on GMail.